# I cannot select the ("text") in my svg when I want to change the values

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have a problem where I can append the text into `SVG` but when I want it to change I can't seem to select it to change. The code above the `d3.select("button")` all works as well as the `bar.transition`. Can someone help me figure out how to select the `"text"` so when I click the button it'll use the new dataset?

```js
var bar = svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter();

bar.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[2]);
  })
  .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - yScale(d[2]);
  })
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    var s = "bar ";
    if (d[2] < 50) {
      return s + "bar1";
    } else if (d[2] < 100) {
      return s + "bar2";
    } else {
      return s + "bar3";
    }
  });

bar.append("text")
  .attr("dy", "1.3em")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return yScale(d[2]);
  })
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("font-size", "11px")
  .attr("fill", "black")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d[2];
  });

d3.select("button")
  .on("click", function() {
    var dataset = [
      ['Jun-19', 8.6, 21.7],
      ['Jul-19', 8.68, 17.98],
      ['Aug-19', 8.9, 25.38],
      ['Sep-19', 6.38, 11.6],
      ['Oct-19', 10.36, 65.08],
      ['Nov-19', 22.36, 125.72],
      ['Dec-19', 26.52, 112.22],
      ['Jan-20', 21.08, 76.1],
      ['Feb-20', 6, 44, 19.625],
      ['Mar-20', 4.68, 8.95],
      ['Apr-20', 7.4, 15.94],
      ['May-20', 7.36, 18.36]
    ];

    bar = svg.selectAll("rect")
      .data(dataset);

    bar.transition()
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]);
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[2]);
      })
      .attr("width", xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", function(d) {
        return height - yScale(d[2]);
      })
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        var s = "bar ";
        if (d[2] < 30) {
          return s + "bar1";
        } else if (d[2] < 60) {
          return s + "bar2";
        } else {
          return s + "bar3";
        }
      });

    svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(dataset)
      .transition()
      .attr("dy", "1.3em")
      .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d[0]) + xScale.bandwidth() / 2;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) {
        return yScale(d[2]);
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", "11px")
      .attr("fill", "black")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d[2];
      });

  });
```

I've tried using `bar.selectAll("text")` but it doesn't work at all, but if I use `svg.selectAll("text")` it takes the ticks from my `Axis.Left` and moves it.

Comment: `svg.selectAll("text")` doesn't differentiate between ticks or other text, try giving the text you want a a class and select by that class when you want to update, alternatively, you could create a `g` to hold the text and bars that are updated, and select with `g.selectAll("text")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot append `text` nodes as children of `rect` nodes - so the SVG probably never renders. Try using a `g` node per bar, and adding both the `rect` and the `text` to that. You can give it class `barContainer`, for example.

As for selecting the `text` and ignoring those from the axes, do as @Andrew Reid said in his comment and use `barContainer.selectAll("text")`. Alternatively, you can give all labels the class `label` and then use `svg.selectAll(".label")`.